# Java generics - assigning Object to a typed value

Tags: java, generics

I have the below setup.

```
interface Initializable<T> {
   T getValue();
   void setValue(T value);
}

class BaseClass {
  
  private final String code; // has getter and setter

  ///
}

class StringValue extends BaseClass implements Initializable<String> {

   private final String value;

   @Override
   public void setValue(String value) {
      this.value = value;
   }

   @Override
   public String getValue() {
      return value;
   }
}

class IntValue extends BaseClass implements Initializable<Integer> {
   
   private final Integer value;

   @Override
   public void setValue(Integer value) {
      this.value = value;
   }

   @Override
   public Integer getValue() {
      return value;
   }
}

class NotInitializable extends BaseClass {

   /////
}
```

I have a list of BaseClass instances and I would like to set value field for Initializable instances as below. I would like to be able to do this without the Raw use.   I can't seem to be able to make that work. Any help is appreciated. TIA

```
List<BaseClass> fields; // populated
Map<String, Object> vauleByCode; // populated

for (final BaseClass bc : fields) {
   if (bc instanceof Initializable) {
     
      // I would like to set this value of type Object to the value field in Initializable
      final Object value = valueByCode.get(bc.getCode());

      // I would not like to use Raw variable here (i. e without the generic ?)
      Initializable<?> init = (Initializable<?>) bc;
      init.setValue(value) // set value here 
   }
}
```

Comment: The second code snippet is probably not the actual "setup" that you "have": it has basic typos in it (`vaule`), and it's using `setValue` without any arguments. Where exactly are you checking that the actual runtime type of the `Object`s that you're getting out of the map actually matches the type of the `bc`-field? What if it attempts to set an integer into a `String`-field, what then?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! That's right, I want to be able to set that dynamically without explicitly checking, using a generic method or some other way.

Comment: Furthermore, since [generics are erased](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), this cannot work without casting (and thus foregoing type safety). The bound `<?>` will also make problems since we cannot determine the type of a generic parameter at runtime.

Comment: _"I want to be able to set that dynamically without explicitly checking"_ - ok, the way you tell it to the compiler is by forcibly casting `bc` into `Initializable<Object>`, and then invoking `bc.setValue(value)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your objective, I have to presume, is to detect type errors, where the value found in `valueByCode` doesn't match the generic type of your `Initializable` instance. For example, you want to make sure you don't pass a `String` to `setValue()` on an object someone references as `Initializable<Integer>`, because that will cause a `ClassCastException` at some distant time and place, at a call site that doesn't have an explicit cast. That would be a bug in this assignment, not in the caller; the assignment should have failed, not silently ignored the type mismatch.

If classes implement `Initializable` as shown in the question, the *type parameter is not erased,* and can be used at runtime to check types. That is, when you define a class like `class StringValue extends BaseClass implements Initializable<String>`, the `String` is compiled into the class, and can be used to enforce type safety at runtime.

You could use reflection (via [`ParameterizedType`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html)) to find the generic type parameter of the `Initializable` implementation, but because those implementations could vary a lot, handling all the possibilities would make that code relatively complex.

Instead, use the raw type (exactly as you said you don't want to do in the question). If there is a type mismatch, a `ClassCastException` will be raised when you call `setValue()`. This preserves generic type safety so that anyone who calls `getValue()` via a generic method will not encounter a `ClassCastException` even though they aren't downcasting the result.